# Activity wont import AdMob AdManager

Tags: android, android-activity, import, admob

I am currently working on implementing an admob adview in my app. I did something similar 5 months ago. However, there seemed to be a problem with the new SDK.
Whenever I use AdManager.setTextDevices, I get an error on AdManager with no option to import admanager, and if I type the import manually, it wont work. I am sure that I have imported the SDK properly. Im currently with 4.3.1. Any ideas?

Comment: I typed, import com.admob.android.ads.AdManager;

Comment: Have you tried adding the ad in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no AdManager.class file in the 4.3.1 AdMob SDK.  If you are trying to set test devices, use `AdRequest.addTestDevice` or `AdRequest.setTestDevices` and `import com.google.ads.AdRequest` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But I found setting up in xml is much easier!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  For others interested in setting up an AdMob banner in xml, please refer to http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html